# How to simulate a 3-stack automaton with a 2-stack automaton?

Tags: automata, turing-machines

Since a 2-stack automaton is Turing-equivalent, it is possible to simulate a 3-stack automaton with just a 2-stack automaton. But how so? How it is normally done?

Comment: Use stack 1 to store the contents of stack A, and use stack 2 to store the contents of stacks B and C, using a marker for each item in stack 2 to indicate whether it's on B or C.  You can "pop" from stack B or C by searching stack 2 for the next item with the appropriate marker.  You have to store the items you go through in stack 1 during the search, but you move them back to the top of stack 2 at the end of the pop.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you meant by "marker". Is this marker a special symbol that every time I read I change the virtual stack, or should I create a special symbol for each original symbol that goes into the stack B for the stack C?

Comment: Either one works.  Probably the easiest thing to do is just double the size of the alphabet.  For example, if your 3-stack machine uses an alphabet of $\{0,1\}$, then you can use symbols $\{0B,0C,1B,1C\}$ for your 2-stack machine.

Comment: @JimBelk Thinking it though I think you might need another symbol so you know when you can stop pushing "back" to stack 2 after a pop. See my answer for the details.

Comment: @AlexR You definitely need to incorporate some mechanism for this.  As you suggest, the easiest thing to do is probably just to add another symbol.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate Jims comment:

Let the 2-stack automaton have stacks $1$ and $2$ and the 3-stack automaton we want to emulate have stacks $A,B$ and $C$.

At the beginning of an operation, stack 1 shall consist of elements from stack A paired with the symbol $a$, written as $(a,e_a)$ and stack 2 shall consist of entries $(m,e)$ where $m \in \{b,c\}$ and $e$ is an element of the respective stacks.

Valid beginning states of the emulator given the 3-stack automaton has $A = (1,2), B = (1,2), C = (1,2,3)$ can be
$$S_1 = ((a,1),(a,2)) \\
S_2 = ((b,1), (c,1), (c,2), (b,2), (c,3))$$

**POP**
popping stack A is simple: just pop stack 1 and return the element

popping stack B or C:

1. Let $s$ be the corresponding marker of the stack to pop from ($b$ for stack $B$ and $c$ for stack $C$)
2. Let $(m,e)$ be popped from stack 2. If $m=s$, continue, else push $(m,e)$ onto stack 1 and redo 2.
3. Let $(n,g)$ be popped from stack 1. If $n=a$, push it back to stack 1 and return $e$. If not, push $(n,g)$ to stack 2. and redo 3.

**PUSH**
pushing $e$ to stack A is pushing $(a,e)$ to stack 1.
pushing $e$ to stack B is pushing $(b,e)$ to stack 2.
pushing $e$ to stack C is pushing $(c,e)$ to stack 2.

You should be able to see that all POP and PUSH operations return the automaton to a valid state and that POP and PUSH of all three stacks works as intended.

---

Pseudocode-ish version:

```
popA:
    (m,e) = pop1();
    return e;
popB:
    (m,e) = pop2();
    while m != b // This is the only difference to popC
        push1(m,e);
        (m,e) = pop2();
    (n,d) = pop1();
    while n != a
        push2(n,d);
        (n,d) = pop1();
    push1(n,d);
    return e;
popC:
    (m,e) = pop2();
    while m != c // This is the only difference to popB
        push1(m,e);
        (m,e) = pop2();
    (n,d) = pop1();
    while n != a
        push2(n,d);
        (n,d) = pop1();
    push1(n,d);
    return e;
pushA(e):
    push1(a,e);
pushB(e):
    push2(b,e);
pushC(e):
    push2(c,e);
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification.